# Usage of Ordering[T] trait

Tags: scala

I have defined a class with a type parameter having an upper bound type and an ordering has been defined for that upper bound type. How do I get "instances/values" of type T,U so I can use them in the isGreaterAnimal method?

```
class Animal[T <: Reflect] {
  implicit val ord = new Ordering[Reflect] {
    def compare(x: Reflect, y: Reflect): Int = if(x.canReflect && !y.canReflect) 1 else if(!x.canReflect && y.canReflect) -1 else 0
  }
  def isGreaterAnimal(that: Animal[T]) = ord.gt(?,?) // ???? 
}

trait Reflect{
  val canReflect: Boolean
}

trait Reflective extends Reflect{
  val canReflect = true
}

trait Automaton extends Reflect{
  val canReflect = false
}


val reflective = new Animal[Reflective]
val robot = new Animal[Automaton]
reflective.isGreaterAnimal(robot)  // should return true
```

Comment: You've defined an ordering for `Reflect`, yet you receive a type `Animal[U]` which doesn't have an ordering defined.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: yes, but the Animal type is having an upper bound of type Reflect. So type parameter U has to be of the kind "Reflect"

Comment: But you don't hold an instance of type `T`. You only receive an instance of type `U`, which you don't have anything to compare with.

Comment: [This works](https://gist.github.com/YuvalItzchakov/88d5a869805bec149ab828f7ca71c400), but doesn't look like you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Yuval. I removed the U type paramter. Will a solution be possible with the new definition for the method now?

Comment: You need two instances of `Reflect` in order to compare them. When you're declaring `class Animal`, you don't take an instance of type `T`, you only declare it as a type parameter. Even if you dropped `U`, where are those instances going to come from? You can create an ordering for `Animal[Reflect]`, but then you the `canReflect` method, because it's defined on `Reflect` itself, not `Animal`.